# HTML::TableExtract: how to run the right argument [see live example]

Tags: mysql, perl, extract, separator, lwp

A question regarding a parser. Is there any chance to catch some separators within the that separate the table...  The paser script runs allready nicely. Note - i want to store the data into a MySQL database. So it would be great to have some seperators - (commas, tabs or somewhat else - a tab seperated values or comma seperated values 
are handy formats to work with...

(  here the data out of the following site:  http://192.68.214.70/km/asps/schulsuche.asp?q=a&a=20  )

> lfd. Nr. Schul- nummer Schulname
>   Straße PLZ Ort Telefon Fax Schulart
>   Webseite 1 0401 Mädchenrealschule
>   Marienburg, Abenberg, der Diözese
>   Eichstätt Marienburg 1 91183 
>   Abenberg   09178/509210  Realschulen 
>   mrs-marienburg.homepage.t-online.de  2
>   6581 Volksschule
>   Abenberg (Grundschule) Güssübelstr. 2
>   91183  Abenberg   09178/215
>   09178/905060 Volksschulen 
>   home.t-online.de/home/vs-abenberg  6
>   3074 Private Berufsschule zur
>   sonderpäd. Förderung,
>   Förderschwerpunkt Lernen, Abensberg
>   Regensburger Straße 60 93326 
>   Abensberg  09443/709191 09443/709193
>   Berufsschulen zur sonderpädog.
>   Förderung
>   www.berufsschule-abensberg.de

Well i need to have those lines divided into at least three columns - take the first record.

> name: Volksschule
>   Abenberg (Grundschule) street:
>   Güssübelstr. 2 postal-code and town:
>   91183  Abenberg fax and telephone:
>   09178/215 09178/905060  type of
>   school: Volksschulen website:
>   home.t-online.de/home/vs-abenberg

Or **even better** - i have divided the postal-code and town into two seperate columns!? 
Question: is this possible?

By the way: see the first record: (here i only show the names of the school)

> 1 0401 Mädchenrealschule
>   Marienburg, Abenberg,  6 3074 Private
>   Berufsschule zur sonderpäd. Förderung,
>   Förderschwerpunkt Lernen, Abensberg

Those have some commas inside the name; does this make it difficult to create a parser that creates csv-fomate?

any idea how to do this in Perl... If possible it would be just great!! 
many many thx for a hint regarding this little issue - besides this all is great and fascinating!

zero

BTW - if you want - i can add the code. No problem here.

```
  #!/usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use HTML::TableExtract;
    use LWP::Simple;
    use Cwd;
    use POSIX qw(strftime);
    my $te = HTML::TableExtract->new;
    my $total_records = 0;
    my $suchbegriffe = "e";
    my $treffer = 50;
    my $range = 0;
    my $url_to_process = "http://192.68.214.70/km/asps/schulsuche.asp?q=";
    my $processdir = "processing";
    my $counter = 50;
    my $displaydate = "";
    my $percent = 0;

    &workDir();
    chdir $processdir;
    &processURL();
    print "\nPress <enter> to continue\n";
    <>;
    $displaydate = strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S', localtime);
    open OUTFILE, ">webdata_for_$suchbegriffe\_$displaydate.txt";
    &processData();
    close OUTFILE;
    print "Finished processing $total_records records...\n";
    print "Processed data saved to $ENV{HOME}/$processdir/webdata_for_$suchbegriffe\_$displaydate.txt\n";
    unlink 'processing.html';
    die "\n";

    sub processURL() {
    print "\nProcessing $url_to_process$suchbegriffe&a=$treffer&s=$range\n";
    getstore("$url_to_process$suchbegriffe&a=$treffer&s=$range", 'tempfile.html') or die 'Unable to get page';

       while( <tempfile.html> ) {
          open( FH, "$_" ) or die;
          while( <FH> ) {
             if( $_ =~ /^.*?(Treffer <b>)(d+)( - )(d+)(</b> w+ w+ <b>)(d+).*/ ) {
                $total_records = $6;
                print "Total records to process is $total_records\n";
                }
             }
             close FH;
       }
       unlink 'tempfile.html';
    }

    sub processData() {
       while ( $range <= $total_records) {
          getstore("$url_to_process$suchbegriffe&a=$treffer&s=$range", 'processing.html') or die 'Unable to get page';
          $te->parse_file('processing.html');
          my ($table) = $te->tables;
          for my $row ( $table->rows ) {
             cleanup(@$row);
             print OUTFILE "@$row\n";
          }
          $| = 1; 
          print "Processed records $range to $counter";
          print "\r";
          $counter = $counter + 50;
          $range = $range + 50;
          $te = HTML::TableExtract->new;
       }
    }

    sub cleanup() {
       for ( @_ ) {
          s/s+/ /g;
       }
    }

    sub workDir() {
    # Use home directory to process data
    chdir or die "$!";
    if ( ! -d $processdir ) {
       mkdir ("$ENV{HOME}/$processdir", 0755) or die "Cannot make directory $processdir: $!";
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use LWP::Simple;
use HTML::TableExtract;
use Text::CSV;

my $html= get 'http://192.68.214.70/km/asps/schulsuche.asp?q=a&a=20';
$html =~ tr/\r//d;     # strip carriage returns
$html =~ s/&nbsp;/ /g; # expand spaces

my $te = new HTML::TableExtract();
$te->parse($html);

my @cols = qw(
    rownum
    number
    name
    phone
    type
    website
);

my @fields = qw(
    rownum
    number
    name
    street
    postal
    town
    phone
    fax
    type
    website
);

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ binary => 1 });

foreach my $ts ($te->table_states) {
    foreach my $row ($ts->rows) {

        #  trim leading/trailing whitespace from base fields
        s/^\s+//, s/\s+$// for @$row;

        # load the fields into the hash using a "hash slice"
        my %h;
        @h{@cols} = @$row;

        # derive some fields from base fields, again using a hash slice
        @h{qw/name street postal town/} = split /\n+/, $h{name};
        @h{qw/phone fax/} = split /\n+/, $h{phone};

        #  trim leading/trailing whitespace from derived fields
        s/^\s+//, s/\s+$// for @h{qw/name street postal town/};

        $csv->combine(@h{@fields});
        print $csv->string, "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: hello tadmc - many many thanks that loooks very imrpessive. martin@suse-linux:~/perl> perl perl_bayern_stack.pl
Can't locate Text/CSV.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.1/i586-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.1 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.12.1/i586-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.12.1 /usr/lib/perl5/5.12.1/i586-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.12.1 .) at perl_bayern_stack.pl line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at perl_bayern_stack.pl line 6.
martin@suse-linux:~/perl>

Comment: hi tadmc - i will try again! btw: on the above mentioned site - i have 6150 results - can i get all (!!) those with the script. Do we need some kind of spider-logic that does the trick here. The above mentioned script (in my posting) has some way to fethc all - unfortunatley it does not take care for the separators.. Yours does this very very well - but at the moment icannot get it to work here... i will look what is wrong ... i come back later to day!! Greetings and many many thanks Zero

Comment: well i see i need text-csv module from cpan - i try to load this on my machine! - i come back later again!! - and report all my findings

Comment: added the perl-module! Great now! one thing left: The results do not take car for the germany vowels -> i have a problem with the special characters. does this have to do with  utf-8 encoding or iso 8859-1 -encoding...Since it has got corrupted characters
--- see a result in the next comment:

Comment: see some results: martin@suse-linux:~/perl> perl perl_bayern_stack.pl "lfd. Nr.","Schul-
nummer",Schulname,Stra�e,PLZ,Ort,Telefon,Fax,Schulart,Webseite
1,0401,"M�dchenrealschule Marienburg, Abenberg, der Di�zese Eichst�tt","Marienburg 1",91183,Abenberg,09178/509210,,Realschulen,mrs-marienburg.homepage.t-online.de
2,6581,"Volksschule Abenberg (Grundschule)","G�ss�belstr. 2",91183,Abenberg,09178/215,09178/905060,Volksschulen,home.t-online.de/home/vs-abenberg

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the use of HTML::Parser module, which you can adjust in order to extract the values of the table cells. See documentation: 
http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::Parser