# How to add CSV-format to LWP::Simple

Tags: mysql, perl, csv, lwp

Regarding this Target-Url a germany schoolary-database http://192.68.214.70/km/asps/schulsuche.asp?q=a&a=100&s=1750

this target url has got a grid- (or a table) - I have a code that runs nicely - but it cannot handle the grid...

it spits out the data like the following ...

```
lfd. Nr. Schul- nummer Schulname Straße PLZ Ort Telefon Fax Schulart Webseite

1 0401 Mädchenrealschule Marienburg, Abenberg, der Diözese Eichstätt Marienburg 1 91183  Abenberg   09178/509210  Realschulen  mrs-marienburg.homepage.t-online.de 
2 6581 Volksschule Abenberg (Grundschule) Güssübelstr. 2 91183  Abenberg   09178/215 09178/905060 Volksschulen  home.t-online.de/home/vs-abenberg 
3 6913 Mittelschule Abenberg  Güssübelstr. 2 91183  Abenberg   09178/215 09178/905060 Volksschulen  home.t-online.de/home/vs-abenberg 
4 0402 Johann-Turmair-Realschule Staatliche Realschule Abensberg Stadionstraße 46 93326  Abensberg   09443/9143-0,12,13 09443/914330 Realschulen  www.rs-abensberg.de
```

That is bad - I need to have a separator - how can I  get some separators into the results - either 
commas or tabs.... ?

Here the code:

```
  #!/usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use HTML::TableExtract;
    use LWP::Simple;
    use Cwd;
    use POSIX qw(strftime);
    my $te = HTML::TableExtract->new;
    my $total_records = 0;
    my $suchbegriffe = "e";
    my $treffer = 50;
    my $range = 0;
    my $url_to_process = "http://192.68.214.70/km/asps/schulsuche.asp?q=";
    my $processdir = "processing";
    my $counter = 50;
    my $displaydate = "";
    my $percent = 0;

    &workDir();
    chdir $processdir;
    &processURL();
    print "\nPress <enter> to continue\n";
    <>;
    $displaydate = strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S', localtime);
    open OUTFILE, ">webdata_for_$suchbegriffe\_$displaydate.txt";
    &processData();
    close OUTFILE;
    print "Finished processing $total_records records...\n";
    print "Processed data saved to $ENV{HOME}/$processdir/webdata_for_$suchbegriffe\_$displaydate.txt\n";
    unlink 'processing.html';
    die "\n";

    sub processURL() {
    print "\nProcessing $url_to_process$suchbegriffe&a=$treffer&s=$range\n";
    getstore("$url_to_process$suchbegriffe&a=$treffer&s=$range", 'tempfile.html') or die 'Unable to get page';

       while( <tempfile.html> ) {
          open( FH, "$_" ) or die;
          while( <FH> ) {
             if( $_ =~ /^.*?(Treffer <b>)(d+)( - )(d+)(</b> w+ w+ <b>)(d+).*/ ) {
                $total_records = $6;
                print "Total records to process is $total_records\n";
                }
             }
             close FH;
       }
       unlink 'tempfile.html';
    }

    sub processData() {
       while ( $range <= $total_records) {
          getstore("$url_to_process$suchbegriffe&a=$treffer&s=$range", 'processing.html') or die 'Unable to get page';
          $te->parse_file('processing.html');
          my ($table) = $te->tables;
          for my $row ( $table->rows ) {
             cleanup(@$row);
             print OUTFILE "@$row\n";
          }
          $| = 1; 
          print "Processed records $range to $counter";
          print "\r";
          $counter = $counter + 50;
          $range = $range + 50;
          $te = HTML::TableExtract->new;
       }
    }

    sub cleanup() {
       for ( @_ ) {
          s/s+/ /g;
       }
    }

    sub workDir() {
    # Use home directory to process data
    chdir or die "$!";
    if ( ! -d $processdir ) {
       mkdir ("$ENV{HOME}/$processdir", 0755) or die "Cannot make directory $processdir: $!";
       }
    }
```

btw - see one example of the separators... :

```
my @cols = qw(
    rownum
    number
    name
    phone
    type
    website
);

my @fields = qw(
    rownum
    number
    name
    street
    postal
    town
    phone
    fax
    type
    website
);
```

note: this steems from a user  that gave me some great hints on this thread. See 
[HTML::TableExtract: how to run the right argument [see live example]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050314/htmltableextract-how-to-run-the-right-argument-see-live-example)

Well - i want to migrate the ideas into the above mentioned spider&parser. Is this possible..Can you give me some hints how to add some lines of code - so that the results are spit out in csv-formate...!?

any and all help will be greatly appreciated..

zero

**Update:** according the ideas of muu is too short...:

```
  #!/usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use HTML::TableExtract;
    use LWP::Simple;
    use Text::CSV
    use Cwd;
    use POSIX qw(strftime);
    my $te = HTML::TableExtract->new;
    my $total_records = 0;
    my $suchbegriffe = "e";
    my $treffer = 50;
    my $range = 0;
    my $url_to_process = "http://192.68.214.70/km/asps/schulsuche.asp?q=";
    my $processdir = "processing";
    my $counter = 50;
    my $displaydate = "";
    my $percent = 0;

    &workDir();
    chdir $processdir;
    &processURL();
    print "\nPress <enter> to continue\n";
    <>;
    $displaydate = strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S', localtime);
    open OUTFILE, ">webdata_for_$suchbegriffe\_$displaydate.txt";
    &processData();
    close OUTFILE;
    print "Finished processing $total_records records...\n";
    print "Processed data saved to $ENV{HOME}/$processdir/webdata_for_$suchbegriffe\_$displaydate.txt\n";
    unlink 'processing.html';
    die "\n";

    sub processURL() {
    print "\nProcessing $url_to_process$suchbegriffe&a=$treffer&s=$range\n";
    getstore("$url_to_process$suchbegriffe&a=$treffer&s=$range", 'tempfile.html') or die 'Unable to get page';

       while( <tempfile.html> ) {
          open( FH, "$_" ) or die;
          while( <FH> ) {
             if( $_ =~ /^.*?(Treffer <b>)(d+)( - )(d+)(</b> w+ w+ <b>)(d+).*/ ) {
                $total_records = $6;
                print "Total records to process is $total_records\n";
                }
             }
             close FH;
       }
       unlink 'tempfile.html';
    }

    sub processData() {
       while ( $range <= $total_records) {
          getstore("$url_to_process$suchbegriffe&a=$treffer&s=$range", 'processing.html') or die 'Unable to get page';
          $te->parse_file('processing.html');
          my ($table) = $te->tables;
          for my $row ( $table->rows ) {
             cleanup(@$row);

            $csv->combine(@$row);
      print OUTFILE $csv->string();

          }
          $| = 1; 
          print "Processed records $range to $counter";
          print "\r";
          $counter = $counter + 50;
          $range = $range + 50;
          $te = HTML::TableExtract->new;
       }
    }


sub cleanup {
   for ( @_ ) {
      s/\s+/ /g;
   }
}
    sub workDir() {
    # Use home directory to process data
    chdir or die "$!";
    if ( ! -d $processdir ) {
       mkdir ("$ENV{HOME}/$processdir", 0755) or die "Cannot make directory $processdir: $!";
       }
    }
```

**Update:** I did some trials:

> martin@suse-linux:~/perl> perl
>   perl_bayern_newstack.pl Unmatched ( in
>   regex; marked by <-- HERE in
>   m/^.*?(Treffer )(d+)( - )(d+)( <--
>   HERE

what is wrong here ...?

Answer (score 2):

You should use [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-CSV/) to build your output, that will save you the hassle of trying to handle embedded quotes and separators by hand. So, create an instance of `Text::CSV` with your desired options and replace this:

```
print OUTFILE "@$row\n";
```

with

```
$csv->combine(@$row);
print OUTFILE $csv->string();
```

Where `$csv` is your `Text::CSV` instance.

Also, your `cleanup` function is a bit broken, it should look like this:

```
sub cleanup {
   for ( @_ ) {
      s/\s+/ /g;
   }
}
```

The missing `\` might be just a typo when you pasted your code in but maybe not.

And don't use prototypes, they don't do what you probably think they do. Where you say:

```
sub cleanup() {
```

just say

```
sub cleanup {
```

And don't call functions with the leading sigil (i.e. don't `&workDir();`, just `workDir();` will do) unless you know what its side effects are.

Comment: hello mu is too short! Many many thanks for the answer. This offers a great help. I now try to add the bits and pieces to the whole thing together. Your tips are great! BTW - i was on your site.- Like what i see. Your pies look fantastic and your philosophy is convincing! Keep up doing such great  things... since you are an angel for all ppl around you. Plz continue do such great things... and yes "do what [ya](I) can to fill grandma's shoes." - many greetings zero

Comment: hello mu is too short: i did some trials martin@suse-linux:~/perl> perl perl_bayern_newstack.pl
Unmatched ( in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^.*?(Treffer <b>)(d+)( - )(d+)( <-- HERE </ at perl_bayern_newstack.pl line 41.
martin@suse-linux:~/perl> 


what is wrong here .."?

Comment: @zero: Looks like you have "`(</b> `", the problem isn't the "(", the problem is the slash in "/b", you want "`(<\/b> `" instead.

Comment: @ mu is too short: i will have a closer look - i come back tomorrow and report all my findings.. Many many thanks so far!! You are great!! - many greetings  to whistler ;-)

Comment: @mu is to short: tried to fix - but now i have the following:martin@suse-linux:~/perl> perl perl_bayern_newstack.pl
Global symbol "$csv" requires explicit package name at perl_bayern_newstack.pl line 59.
Global symbol "$csv" requires explicit package name at perl_bayern_newstack.pl line 60.Execution of perl_bayern_newstack.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
Hmmm - what can this be"? What causes the errors? This goes a bit over my head. Can you help me with the code - perhaps put it together. That would  be  very very supportive...Thx in advance -many gretings  to whistler - zero

Comment: @zero: You need to create an instance of `Text::CSV`, something like `my $csv = Text::CSV->new({binary => 1});` at the beginning of `processData`. `Text::CSV` has other options that you may be interested in, check the documentation (http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::CSV) for details.